# Using a Calendar for an appointment scheduler with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, calendar, scheduler

I am trying to make an appointment scheduler with
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-calendar
I am having a hard time getting an hour and disabling a date that's already scheduled.
I end up disabling that date for every month.
Should I use another NPM or API?

Also here is the full project on GitHub. I finished my Bootcamp but what to continue working on my project: https://github.com/RyanBajzath/Massage_therapy_booking

```
const SchedulePage = () => {
  const [value, onChange] = useState(new Date());
  // console.log(value);
  const { user } = useAuth0();
  const activeStartDate = new Date();
  const date1 = new Date(2022, 8, 22);
  const date2 = new Date(2022, 8, 25);
  const disabledDates = [date1.getDate(), date2.getDate()];
  console.log(new Date(2022, 8, 22));
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    fetch(`/profiles/${user.sub}`, {
      method: "PATCH",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        appointment: value,
      }),
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        data.status === 200 &&
          Swal.fire({
            icon: "success",
            title: "Success",
            text: "Appointment Updated",
            footer: '<a href="/fetchprofilepage">View Profile</a>',
          });
        data.status === 404 &&
          Swal.fire({
            icon: "error",
            title: "Failure",
            text: "Profile Needs to be created",
            footer: '<a href="/createprofilepage">Go to Create Profile</a>',
          });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error:", error);
      });
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <ScheduleDiv>
        <StyledCalendar
          onChange={onChange}
          value={value}
          tileDisabled={
            ({ activeStartDate, date }) =>
              date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 1
            // ||
            // disabledDates.includes(date.getDate())
          }
        />
        <ButtonDiv>
          <Button>Create Appointment</Button>

          <PandaMilk src="https://media.giphy.com/media/PeGgFlioo8EbstEQH4/giphy.gif" />
        </ButtonDiv>
      </ScheduleDiv>
    </form>
  );
};
```

Comment: https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-calendar/issues/103